# Trying to find a book about a human colony that communicates with other colonies with their minds

Tags: story-identification, books, mind-control

In the book, humans use these devices to basically go into the body of other humans in other colonies. However, they think it is a game so they continue to destroy the lives of the people they go into. There is someone that realizes this and tries to get back to Earth. There is also a colony that no one likes to go to when "playing this game" because they have evolved to read minds and can tell when someone has been taken over.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  When did you read this?

Comment: I read it quite a long time ago. Maybe 5 years?